# Indy - IdHttp how to handle page redirects?

Tags: delphi, indy, web-scraping

Using: Delphi 2010, latest version of Indy

I am trying to scrape the data off Googles Adsense web page, with an aim to get the reports. However I have been unsuccessful so far. It stops after the first request and does not proceed.

Using Fiddler to debug the traffic/requests to Google Adsense website, and a web browser to load the Adsense page, I can see that the request (from the webbrowser) generates a number of redirects until the page is loaded.

However, my Delphi application is only generating a couple of requests before it stops.

Here are the steps I have followed:

1. Drop a IdHTTP and a IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1 component on the form.
2. Set the IdHTTP component properties AllowCookies and HandleRedirects to True, and IOHandler property to the IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1.
3. Set the IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1 component property Method := 'sslvSSLv23'

Finally I have this code:

```
procedure TfmMain.GetUrlToFile(AURL, AFile : String);
var
 Output : TMemoryStream;
begin
  Output := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    IdHTTP1.Get(FURL, Output);
    Output.SaveToFile(AFile);
  finally
    Output.Free;
  end;
end;
```

However, it does not get to the login page as expected. I would expect it to behave as if it was a webbrowser and proceed through the redirects until it finds the final page.

This is the output of the headers from Fiddler:

> ```
> HTTP/1.1 302 Found
> Location: https://encrypted.google.com/
> Cache-Control: private
> Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
> Set-Cookie: PREF=ID=5166063f01b64b03:FF=0:TM=1293571783:LM=1293571783:S=a5OtsOqxu_GiV3d6; expires=Thu, 27-Dec-2012 21:29:43 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com
> Set-Cookie: NID=42=XFUwZdkyF0TJKmoJjqoGgYNtGyOz-Irvz7ivao2z0--pCBKPpAvCGUeaa5GXLneP41wlpse-yU5UuC57pBfMkv434t7XB1H68ET0ZgVDNEPNmIVEQRVj7AA1Lnvv2Aez; expires=Wed, 29-Jun-2011 21:29:43 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; HttpOnly
> Date: Tue, 28 Dec 2010 21:29:43 GMT
> Server: gws
> Content-Length: 226
> X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
> ```

Firstly, is there anything wrong with this output?

Is there something more that I should do to get the IdHTTP component to keep pursuing the redirects until the final page?

Comment: Why aren't you using [the API](http://code.google.com/apis/adsense/developer/ReportService.html)?

Comment: To apply for access to the Google Adsesnse API requires that your website gets 100,000 page views or more per day. This website does not qualify, so I have to do a manual scrape of the page.

Comment: Maybe there is Javascript involved (you can disable it in the browser to verify - if the login still works, this proves I was wrong)

Comment: @mjn: Disabled JavaScript, cleared browser cache and reloaded the page - the login page loads fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

IdHTTP component property values prior to making the call:

```
    Name := 'IdHTTP1';
    IOHandler := IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1;
    AllowCookies := True;
    HandleRedirects := True;
    RedirectMaximum := 35;
    Request.UserAgent := 
      'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:2.0b8) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.' +
      '0b8';
    HTTPOptions := [hoForceEncodeParams];
    OnRedirect := IdHTTP1Redirect;
    CookieManager := IdCookieManager1;
```

Redirect event handler:

```
procedure TfmMain.IdHTTP1Redirect(Sender: TObject; var dest: string; var
    NumRedirect: Integer; var Handled: Boolean; var VMethod: string);
begin
   Handled := True;
end;
```

Making the call:

```
  FURL := 'https://www.google.com';

  GetUrlToFile( (FURL + '/adsense/'), 'a.html');




  procedure TfmMain.GetUrlToFile(AURL, AFile : String);
  var
   Output : TMemoryStream;
  begin
    Output := TMemoryStream.Create;
    try
      try
       IdHTTP1.Get(AURL, Output);
       IdHTTP1.Disconnect;
      except

      end;
      Output.SaveToFile(AFile);
    finally
      Output.Free;
    end;
  end;
```

Here's the (request and response headers) output from Fiddler:

[image]

Comment: this belongs in the original question (you may edit your question any time you want). Is TIdHTTP handling any redirects? Is this the first redirect you *ever* see or is this simply the last redirect? Put a brake point in IdHTTP1Redirect, is it ever stopping?

Answer (score 2):

### Getting redirects going

`TIdHTTP.HandleRedirects := True` so it starts automatically handling redirects.

`TIdHTTP.RedirectMaximum`  is used to set how many successive redirects should be handled.

---

Alternatively you may assign `TIdHTTP.OnRedirect` and set `Handled := True` from that handler. This is what I'm doing in a project that needs to read data from a WikiMedia web site (my own site).

### About the HTTP response

Nothing wrong with that response, it's a very basic redirect to https://encrypted.google.com/. TIdHTTP should go to the given page in response. It also sets some cookies.

### Other suggestions

Don't forget to assign an `CookieManager` and make sure you use the same `CookieManager` for all subsequent requests. If you don't you'll probably get redirected to the login page over and over again.

Comment: [(*
About the HTTP response

Nothing wrong with that response, it's a very basic redirect to https://encrypted.google.com/. TIdHTTP should go to the given page in response. It also sets some cookies.
*)]
Can you tell me how IdHTTP should go to that given page?

Comment: TIdHttp handles 302 status messages automatically and loads the new page automatically if you set HandleRedirects = True.

Comment: I have done all that you say above. However, still no joy. It stops at a redirection and does not proceed (as is viewable from the request headers in Fiddler).     --     What (code or property setting) is required to make IdHTTP keep following through until the last page? ie. what do I need to do to get IdHttp to act like a web-browser? (in my case I need to get to the Adsense login page; if already logged-in to Adsense then it is the Adsense home page that I need to download)

Comment: Please show the final HTTP reply that TIdHTTP receives before it stops following redirects.  Either Google actually stops sending redirects, or it is sending a reply that TIdHTTP cannot handle.

Comment: @Remy: Code and response/request headers posted as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I needed to fix dest, because somehow I had ; in it!

```
procedure Tfrm1.IdHTTP1Redirect(Sender: TObject; var dest: string;
  var NumRedirect: Integer; var Handled: Boolean; var VMethod: string);
var
  i: Integer;
begin

  i := Pos(';', dest);
  if i > 0 then
  begin
    dest := Copy(dest,1, i - 1);
  end;

  Handled := True;
end;
```